# Bash if condition: "-gt" vs ">" when using [[

Tags: bash, shell

When I ran the following script

```
if [[ 10 -gt 2 ]]
then
    echo "10 is greater than 2"
else
    echo "10 is less than 2"
fi
```

it output the expected result

```
10 is greater than 2
```

However, when I ran the following one

```
if [[ 10 > 2 ]]
then
    echo "10 is greater than 2"
else
    echo "10 is less than 2"
fi
```

it output the following result

```
10 is less than 2
```

It seems like it's performing String comparison in this case. What are the logics behind these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have guessed, `>` performs string comparison and `-gt` performs numeric comparison. This is documented in [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §6.4 "Bash Conditional Expressions"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

Comment: The `>` string comparison operator is also mentioned in the [POSIX standard for the `test` / `[ ]` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), although it's not actually part of the standard; but if your `test` / `[ ]` command supports it, it should have the same semantics. One difference from `[[ ]]`, though: `test` and `[ ]` are normal commands, so `>` will be parsed as an output redirect unless it's quoted or escaped.